# Building AMD code for Node and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, js-amd

I have been searching around various repositories and blogs around the web and can't seem to find what I am looking for.

**The Problem**

When building code via AMD using something like RequireJS you can expect to set up your modules like so:

Module one:

```
define(['a'], function () {
    return {
        methodOne: function () {
            return 'something';
        }
    }
});
```

Module two:

```
define(['b'], function () {
    return {
        methodTwo: function () {
            return 'something';
        }
    }
});
```

This helps a lot with building a project.  It helps separates concerns out into multiple files rather than having one large one.

But how do you optimize this into one file?  I would assume that you would use some sort of build tool and come out with something like:

```
define(function () {
    return {
        /* other dependency functions */

        methodOne: function () {
            return 'something';
        },

        methodTwo: function () {
            return 'something';
        }
    }
});
```

For AMD environments.  This essentially would just combine all of the modules together into one file.

So I have a few questions:

- How would I optimize my AMD code correctly in a build like I've
  mentioned above?  Is this even the best approach?
- How do I make my code portable for AMD, Node and the browser??

**What I've Tried/Found**

It looks like RequireJS has it's own build tool (http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to do something like this.  After going through the documentation and trying out the build tool for myself, I've found that it just combines all of the `defines` into one file.  Am I missing something here?  This isn't very useful.

The UMD pattern seems to be what normalizes your code to work with AMD, Node and the browser (http://know.cujojs.com/tutorials/modules/authoring-umd-modules, https://github.com/umdjs/umd).  Does this mean that every AMD file I am using I have to convert to UMD?  This seems like a headache.

I have stumbled upon uRequire (http://urequire.org/) which seems like it's the answer I am looking for.  Being able to build code into UMD from AMD or CommonJS pattern.

This is an issue that has been eluding me.  UMD looks cool, but it seems like the hangup there is making your code available for the browser easily.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: RequireJS combining is for *distribution*; it can be used fine without such. In Node.js this combining might be during a build phase for internal modules (while leaving some modules external).

Comment: @user2864740, what do you mean by that?  Making it ready for production?

Comment: For "public facing deployment on a website". It still loads the modules dynamically (that is, it does not statically build up the call graph) but there is only one file.

Comment: @user2864740, yeah, but combing all of the defines into one file seems to go against the very nature of AMD.  Is there a build profile for RequireJS I am missing here?

Comment: The optimization phase *is* the "build profile". The idea is that if it works with many files that, after the optimization for *distribution*, it will also work with one file. For internal projects and development there is little point to run the optimization step. For external websites, fetching 1 resource vs 20 resources can make a huge difference.

Comment: @user2864740, my tests prove otherwise.  After using the r.js optimization all I have found is that it concatenates my modules into one file with multiple `define` calls.  Trying to load that into the browser returns `undefined`.  I am mostly asking what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: If you get "undefined" when loading it, then you're doing something wrong. Or RequireJS is broken. Take your pick. (Hint: it's not the latter.)

Comment: @user2864740, but the desired output is multiple `define`s in one file, right?

Comment: Yes. The RequireJS optimizer combines the resources; it does *not* statically handle the module call-graph. The loading is still done with dynamic (which is why there are define's) resolution.

Comment: @user2864740, well, I guess I have to play with the optimizer a bit more than to see where I went wrong.  That answers that question at least.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the RequireJS optimizer usefulness, I use the RequireJS rjs optimizer for over a year to create bundles of modules that have to come together (and synchronously).

This is being very helpful because I am saving on the number of requests and also on the asynchronous overhead where require has to figure out all the dependency tree, because that simply doesn't need to happen.

For instance, if you think in terms of broader modules, a.k.a. sub-applications or even features, you can just give another lecture to your app where instead of loading 40+ requirejs modules you would then be loading just 5 sub-apps/features, and each block of them would come altogether and synchronously.

Regarding UMD and uRequire, I suggest having a look also on https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs - it seems to be a clever approach. Yet uRequire seems to be very nice as well.